# If $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} : \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, is the set $\{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(u) = 0\}$ closed and bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} : \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, is the
>   set $\{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(u) = 0\}$ closed and bounded?

I think that the set is closed. We can write the set as

$$\{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(u) \geq 0\} \cap \{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(u) \leq 0\}, $$

and there is a theorem in my book that these two sets are closed provided that $f$ is continuous (which it is). Thus, it is the intersection of two closed sets, which is closed.

I also think that the set is bounded. We want to show that for all $x$ in our set, $||x|| \leq B$  for some bound $B$. I have no idea how to show this though; it's completely based off of my intuition. I tried making some sequences, and using the fact that the image sequence must also converge to the image of the limit point (due to convergence), but I got nowhere. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You are correct that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. As for boundedness, consider $f(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1$.

Comment: The zero function is continuous. What happens to the set in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set

$f^{-1}(u) = \{u \in \Bbb R^n \mid f(u) = 0 \} \tag 1$

is, as our OP daheckimgood has properly shown, is always closed for continuous $f$.  It is not, in general, bounded.

***Counterexample:*** Take $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ to be any non-trivial linear functional.  Then

$\exists 0 \ne v \in \ker f \subset \Bbb R^n; \tag 2$

then

$\forall r \in \Bbb R, \; f(rv) = rf(v) = 0; \tag 3$

however, the set

$\{rv, \; r \in \Bbb R \} \subset f^{-1}(0) \tag 4$

is mos' def' not bounded.